# Check if a number exists in contacts using PhoneNumberUtils.compare()

Tags: java, android

I have a number with the country code. I want to check if that number exists in the contacts, but it would be hard to tell, since I may or may not have stored the contact withe country code. So is there anyway I can check if a number (with country code prefixed) exists in contacts (ignoring the prefix. Something like PhoneNumberUtils.compare())

This is the code, but if I don't have the number stored with country code, it won't return true.

```
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number) {
    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(number));
    String[] mPhoneNumberProjection = { ContactsContract.PhoneLookup._ID,
            ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.NUMBER, ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };
    Cursor cur = context.getContentResolver().query(lookupUri,mPhoneNumberProjection, null, null, null);
    try {
        if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        if (cur != null)
            cur.close();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing it this way.

```
public boolean contactExists(Context context, String number, ContentResolver contentResolver) {
    Cursor phones = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.
            CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    while (phones.moveToNext()){
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        if(PhoneNumberUtils.compare(number, phoneNumber)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```